# Accessing nested json objects using python

Tags: python, json, parsing

I am trying to interact with an API and running into issues accessing nested objects. Below is sample json output that I am working with.

```
{
    "results": [
        {
            "task_id": "22774853-2b2c-49f4-b044-2d053141b635",
            "params": {
                "type": "host",
                "target": "54.243.80.16",
                "source": "malware_analysis"
            },
            "v": "2.0.2",
            "status": "success",
            "time": 227,
            "data": {
                "details": {
                    "as_owner": "Amazon.com, Inc.",
                    "asn": "14618",
                    "country": "US",
                    "detected_urls": [],
                    "resolutions": [
                        {
                            "hostname": "bumbleride.com",
                            "last_resolved": "2016-09-15 00:00:00"
                        },
                        {
                            "hostname": "chilitechnology.com",
                            "last_resolved": "2016-09-16 00:00:00"
                        }
                    ],
                    "response_code": 1,
                    "verbose_msg": "IP address in dataset"
                },
                "match": true
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

The deepest I am able to access is the data portion which returns too much.... ideally I am just trying access as_owner,asn,country,detected_urls,resolutions

When I try to access details / response code ... etc I will get a KeyError. My nested json goes deeper then other Q's mentioned and I have tried that logic.

Below is my current code snippet and any help is appreciated!

```
import requests
import json
headers = {
   'Content-Type': 'application/json',
}

params = (
   ('wait', 'true'),
)

data = '{"target":{"one":{"type": "ip","target": "54.243.80.16", "sources": ["xxx","xxxxx"]}}}'

r=requests.post('https://fakewebsite:8000/api/services/intel/lookup/jobs', headers=headers, params=params, data=data, auth=('apikey', ''))
parsed_json = json.loads(r.text)
#results = parsed_json["results"]
for item in parsed_json["results"]:
     print(item['data'])
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python Accessing Nested JSON Data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23306653/python-accessing-nested-json-data)

Comment: There are already a lot of questions which have been answered for a similar query. Please refer the question base before posting a question.

Comment: Please try to attach the error log (for these type of queries) so that it would be helpful for us to answer to the point

Comment: ...I explained a KeyError....

Answer (score 0):

You just need to index correctly into the converted JSON. Then you can easily loop over a list of the keys you want to fetch, since they are all in the "details" dictionary.

```
import json

raw = '''\
{
    "results": [
        {
            "task_id": "22774853-2b2c-49f4-b044-2d053141b635",
            "params": {
                "type": "host",
                "target": "54.243.80.16",
                "source": "malware_analysis"
            },
            "v": "2.0.2",
            "status": "success",
            "time": 227,
            "data": {
                "details": {
                    "as_owner": "Amazon.com, Inc.",
                    "asn": "14618",
                    "country": "US",
                    "detected_urls": [],
                    "resolutions": [
                        {
                            "hostname": "bumbleride.com",
                            "last_resolved": "2016-09-15 00:00:00"
                        },
                        {
                            "hostname": "chilitechnology.com",
                            "last_resolved": "2016-09-16 00:00:00"
                        }
                    ],
                    "response_code": 1,
                    "verbose_msg": "IP address in dataset"
                },
                "match": true
            }
        }
    ]
}
'''

parsed_json = json.loads(raw)

wanted = ['as_owner', 'asn', 'country', 'detected_urls', 'resolutions']

for item in parsed_json["results"]:
    details = item['data']['details']
    for key in wanted:
        print(key, ':', json.dumps(details[key], indent=4))
    # Put a blank line at the end of the details for each item
    print()
```

**output**

```
as_owner : "Amazon.com, Inc."
asn : "14618"
country : "US"
detected_urls : []
resolutions : [
    {
        "hostname": "bumbleride.com",
        "last_resolved": "2016-09-15 00:00:00"
    },
    {
        "hostname": "chilitechnology.com",
        "last_resolved": "2016-09-16 00:00:00"
    }
]
```

---

BTW, when you fetch JSON data using `requests` there's no need to use `json.loads`: you can access the converted JSON using the `.json` method of the returned `request` object instead of using its `.text` attribute.

---

Here's a more robust version of the main loop of the above code. It simply ignores any missing keys. I didn't post this code earlier because the extra `if` tests make it slightly less efficient, and I didn't know that keys *could* be missing.

```
for item in parsed_json["results"]:
    if not 'data' in item:
        continue
    data = item['data']
    if not 'details' in data:
        continue
    details = data['details']
    for key in wanted:
        if key in details:
            print(key, ':', json.dumps(details[key], indent=4))
    # Put a blank line at the end of the details for each item
    print()
```

Comment: `Traceback (most recent call last):
        "hostname": "bumbleride.com",
        "last_resolved": "2016-09-15 00:00:00"
  File "C:/Users/Test/PycharmProjects/dnsdumpster/testt.py", line 21, in <module>
    details =item['data']['details']
KeyError: 'details'
 },`



I do get output in the console sometimes but others I get the Key error mentioned above

Comment: @user2934204 You should have mentioned that sometimes the "details" section may be missing. That's easy to deal with. Are there any other keys that might be missing? Will _every_ item in a "results" list _always_ contain a "data" section? How about 'as_owner', 'asn', 'country', 'detected_urls', 'resolutions'?

Comment: I apologize for not knowing that details may be missing. Basically this is querying a threat service. If there isn't a match for the specified field, theoretically the details section would be missing. It will always contain a data section regardless if there is any matches or not.

Comment: @user2934204 Ok. I've just added some more code that handles _any_ missing keys.