# Nested JSON retrieve values

Tags: python, json, list, dictionary

I have a nested JSON object having the following structure. I would like to retrieve all nested level `"concept"` elements under the main level `"details"`. I'm having trouble in accessing those inner layers of json recursively and getting it's corresponding values..

```
d = {"canonical": None, 
     "concept": "_MAIN", 
     "correct_string": "xxx", 
     "definition": "",
     "details": [{
                   "details": [{
                        "concept": "_A",
                            "details": [{
                                "concept": "_B",
                                    "details": [{
                                        "concept": "_C",
                                            "details": [{
                                                "concept": "_D", ....
```

Expected output:

```
details_concepts = ['_A', '_B', 'C', 'D']
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python Accessing Nested JSON Data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23306653/python-accessing-nested-json-data)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using recursion, you can check for base case using key `concept` and return values on passing base condition as follows:

```
def get_data_by_key(data):
    if 'concept' in data:
        yield data['concept']
    details = data.get('details')
    if details:
        if isinstance(details, list):
            for inner_item in details:
                for i in get_data_by_key(inner_item):
                    yield i


data = {'canonical': None, 'concept': '_MAIN', 'correct_string': 'xxx', 'definition': '',
        'details': [{'concept': '_A', 'details': [{'concept': '_B', 'details': [{'concept': '_C'}]}]}]}
concepts = list(get_data_by_key(data['details'][0]))
print(concepts)

output : ['_A', '_B', '_C']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do this by using `Recursion`, check the following code

```
d={"canonical": None,
     "concept": "_MAIN", 
     "correct_string": "xxx", 
     "definition": "",
     "details": [{
                   "details": [{
                        "concept": "_A",
                            "details": [{
                                "concept": "_B"
                    }]
                }]
        }]
  }
details_concepts=[]
def parse_json(det):
    if 'concept' in det[0]:
        details_concepts.append(det[0]['concept'])
    if 'details' in det[0]:
        return parse_json(det[0]['details'])
    else:
        return details_concepts
print(parse_json(d['details']))
```

I considered your inner details list has only single dictionary, that's the reason I kept `det[0]` directly.