# Python - accessing a value within in a nested dictionary within a list

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I have a JSON API response that looks like the following:

```
json_data=

{
    "sales_list": [
        {
            "date": "all",
            "country": "all",
            "units": {
                "product": {
                    "promotions": 0,
                    "downloads": 1,
                    "updates": 2,
                    "refunds": 3
                },
                "iap": {
                    "promotions": 0,
                    "sales": 0,
                    "refunds": 0
                }
            },
            "revenue": {
                "product": {
                    "promotions": "0.00",
                    "downloads": "0.00",
                    "updates": "0.00",
                    "refunds": "0.00"
                },
                "iap": {
                    "promotions": "0.00",
                    "sales": "0.00",
                    "refunds": "0.00"
                },
                "ad": "0.00"
            }
        }
    ],
    "next_page": null,
    "code": 200,
    "prev_page": null,
    "vertical": "apps",
    "page_num": 1,
    "iap_sales_list": [],
    "currency": "USD",
    "page_index": 0,
    "market": "ios"
}
```

I'm using Python and am trying to access the first "downloads" value in the response. So I need to go from sales_list (list in a dict) > units (dict) > product (dict) > downloads. How to I got about digging down these multiple layers to access just this single value?

I've seen questions about accessing values within a dictionary within a list, or within a nested dictionary. But I'm a little confused as to how to navigate between/among lists in dictionaries and dictionaries in lists. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

similiar question: [Python Accessing Nested JSON Data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23306653/python-accessing-nested-json-data)

is that what you need?

```
print(json_data['sales_list'][0]['units']['product']['downloads'])
```

it gives output `1`

to answer your question:
as you see your json field `sales_list` is one-element list of dictionaries
`[ {dictionary with field you need}, {other dict}, .. ]`
because of that you need to specify index of list element you want to acces - in case of your one-element list it will be `[0]` because first element of your list contains field you need

Comment: Yes this is very helpful — I had been using `json_data['sales_list']['units']['product']['downloads']`, without the `[0]`. What is the function of that component?

Comment: which component function you mean?

Comment: In other words, why does the `[0]` need to be specified? What does it do?

Comment: yes, it makes sense. thanks for taking the time to explain!

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> dict['sales_list'][0]['units']['products']['downloads']
1
```