# How to extract nested json from api

Tags: python, json, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I need help to get some json data from Pipedrive API(just a resquest.get), however, as expected, the json file is not formatted at all.
As you can see in my python script bellow, I'll upload that file to my S3 Bucket, so I can create tables in AWS Glue.
I'm having a lot of trouble to make this json file "readable" in AWS structure.

- Sample of json file I'm working: [I need the "deals" section]

`{"success":true,"data":[{"period_start":"2020-11-12 00:00:00","period_end":"2020-11-12 23:59:59","deals":[{"id":xx,"creator_user_id":xx,"user_id":XX,"person_id":XX,"org_id":XX,"stage_id":X}]}]}`

- Python script:

````
from datetime import datetime
import boto3
import requests
from jsonpath_ng import parse
import pandas as pd

now = datetime.now()
day_int = now.strftime("%d")
month_int = now.strftime("%m")
year_int = now.strftime("%Y")
yesterday = (int(day_int) - 1)
if yesterday == 0:
    yesterday = 31
#today = now.strftime("%Y" + "-" + "%m" + "-" + str(yesterday))
today = '2020-11-12'

response_01 = requests.get(
    'https://api.pipedrive.com/v1/deals/timeline?start_date=' + str(today) + '&interval=day&amount=' + str(
        days) + '&field_key=update_time&totals_convert_currency=' + currency + '&api_token=' + token_api)
raw_data = response_01.json()
x = ([match.value for match in parse('$..deals.[*].[*]').find(raw_data)])
y = json.dumps(x, default= str)

s3 = boto3.resource(
    's3',
    region_name=data_region,
    aws_access_key_id=key_id,
    aws_secret_access_key=access_key
)
client = boto3.client('s3')
client.put_object(Body=str(raw_data), Bucket='bucket_key', Key='object_key') ```
````

Comment: Did you check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23306653/python-accessing-nested-json-data. According to that link, you should try accessing raw_data['data'][0]['deals'].

Comment: Yesterday's date is easier to calculate than you do it. Use `from datetime import date, timedelta` and then `yesterday = date.today() - timedelta(days=1)`.

Comment: Thanks a lot guys, I end up doing a conversion to a Dataframe, then a CSV file thru this:

Comment: raw_data2 = raw_data_r['data']
    list_data = pandas.json_normalize(raw_data2)
    csv_data = list_data.to_csv(index=False, header=True, sep=',', quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)